# Visual Studio Mac 2022 versione 17.5.4 (8) - abdroandroid failed to load solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When opening a Android solution it give this error:

'abdroandroid' is an undeclared prefix
Line 6, position 14.

Someone understand what it mean?

Comment: please edit your title to correctly reflect the problem you're trying to solve.  Have you examined your `csproj` file for  `abdroandroid` and compared it to a working Android `csproj`?

Comment: yes I have examined and they are identical, the problem born every time I close and reopen the solution

Comment: Help -> Report a Problem

Comment: Yes I have already submitted the error